# Do ultrapowers of classical Banach spaces have unconditional bases?

Tags: banach-spaces, ultrapowers, fa.functional-analysis

I am trying to imagine (to some extent, of course) the geometry of ultrapowers of certain 'easy-to-handle' Banach spaces. Let me start with $X = \ell_p$, $p\in (1,\infty)$ or $X=c_0$.

Since the differences between *partiuclar* choices of ultrafilters are not clear to me enough, let me take *any* free ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ over an arbitrary infinite index set $I$.

So, my beginners question is, does the ultrapower $(X)_\mathcal{U}$ have an unconditional basis?

Comment: For anything interesting to happen, you want a non-principal ultrafilter. Otherwise the ultrapower will just be $X$.

Comment: Another issue with the generality in which you have posed the question is that if $I$ is very large and there is a measurable cardinal, then the ultrafilter you use on $I$ might be complete beyond the size of $X$, in which case the ultrapower of $X$ will again just be $X$, even though the ultrafilter is nonprincipal. 

Comment: Andrew, in this context, "free" means "non-principal".

Comment: Bill, since "free" was added to the question in the (currently) latest edit, I conjecture that it was added as a result of Andrew's comment.

Comment: Yes, apologies for not pointing it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $\ell_1$ and $c_0$, the answer to your (implicit) question is easy.  If you take a free ultrafilter on the natural numbers (or most any ultrafilter used in Banach space theory) the ultrapower contains $L_1$ (or $C[0,1]$) and hence does not have an unconditional basis.

For $\ell_p$, $1<p\not= 2 < \infty$,  the situation might be trickier.  Enflo and Rosenthal

Some results concerning Lp(μ)-spaces. 
J. Functional Analysis 14 (1973), 325–348

proved that if $\mu$ is a finite measure s.t. the density character of $L_p(\mu)$ is at least $\aleph_\omega$, then $L_p(\mu)$ does not embed into a space that has an unconditional basis. Now such an $L_p(\mu)$ embeds into some ultrapower of $\ell_p$ but I don't know off the top of my head that when the density character of $L_p(\mu)$ is equal to $\aleph_\omega$ [EDIT: I meant $\aleph_1$ here] whether (under some or any set theoretic axioms about the size of $\aleph_\omega$ [EDIT: I meant $\aleph_1$ here]) $L_p(\mu)$ embeds into an ultrapower of $\ell_p$ when the ultrafilter is a free ultrafilter on the natural numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps I should restrict my attention to ultrafilters over integers only.

Comment: Bill, I'm confused --- isn't any ultrapower of a Hilbert space also a Hilbert space, and doesn't every Hilbert space have an unconditional basis?

Comment: Sure, Nik.  I should have written $1<p\not= 2 < \infty$. I'll edit.

Comment: Bill: To embed such $L_p(\mu)$ into an ultrapower of $l_p$ with an ultrafilter on $\omega$ you need (at the very least) that $2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_\omega$.

Comment: Sorry, Ramiro; I meant $\aleph_1$ at that point. I'll edit again, but make it clear that it is an edit so that your comment makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers/comments. Of course, any further partial positive/negative/'undecidable' answers will be much appreciated.